# C# inserting table, error

Tags: c#, mysql

I have trouble inserting data into my table. I don't know what is the database model or schema looks like cause i am just finding and fixing error on the existing program until i encounter this error

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_database`.`movies_class`, CONSTRAINT `fk_movies_class_movies1` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies_notworking` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and here is my code

```
public void tabinsertcheck(MySqlConnection myconn, DataGridView dgv, int intid)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dgv[0, i].Value != null)
            {
                if ((bool)dgv[0, i].Value)
                {
                    StringBuilder sqry = new StringBuilder();
                    sqry.Append("select max(id) from movies_class");
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqry.ToString(), myconn);
                    int max_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())+1;
                    sqry = new StringBuilder();
                    sqry.Append(String.Format("insert into movies_class values({0},{1},{2})",
                        max_id,intid, dgv[3, i].Value.ToString()));

                    if (myconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        myconn.Open();
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqry.ToString(), myconn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    myconn.Close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I am using loop because i have a lot of checkbox every checkbox it is saving in database, and i don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to insert a row into the `movies_class` table with a value for `movie_id` field that does not exist in the `movies_notworking` table `Id` field. Check your data and make sure that you are inserting right values for the reference fields in the table.

Comment: sorry i can't vote you up, i need 15 rep.. but i accept your answer. thanks